# Как нужно модифицировать алгоритм Дейкстры для решения задачи коммивояжера?

Tags: алгоритм

Дело в том, что алгоритм Дейкстры находит кратчайшее расстояние между данной точкой и всеми остальными. В случае же задачи коммивояжера начальная точка является конечной (коммивояжер должен объехать все города и вернуться в исходный пункт).

**Обновление**

В моём понимании задача коммивояжера это задача нахождения кратчайшего пути, но с некоторыми оговорками. Как я уже писал, алгоритм Дейкстры может найти кратчайшее расстояние между данной точкой и всеми остальными. В случае же с коммивояжером конечная точка = начальная точка + всё точки должны быть посещены. К тому же меня не интересуют иные алгоритмы, раз уж я поднял вопрос об алгоритме Дейкстры.

Решение задачи остается за мной, я лишь задал вопрос, как нужно дополнить алгоритм Дейкстры, чтобы

1. исходная точка была и конечной;
2. чтобы были посещены все вершины графа без повторов.

Ведь Алгоритм Дейкстры позволяет "решить граф", что и нужно сделать в задаче коммивояжера, но чистым этот алгоритм применить нельзя.

** Обновление 2 **

Нашел пару статей на предмет применимости алгоритма Дейкстры для решения задачи, но не могу понять, как авторы предлагают изменить алгоритм для его применения для решения задачи коммивояжера. 
Статья 1 http://www.rusnauka.com/36_NIO_2008/Matemathics/39016.doc.htm
Статья 2 http://ref.by/refs/49/33898/1.html

Comment: Задача коммивояжера - NP-полная, т.е. по сути полный перебор нужен, никаких "модификаций для решения" быть не может

Comment: Очень просто. (1) Берёте алгоритм Дейкстры, (2) Стираете его, записываете вместо него любой алгоритм решения задачи коммивояжёра, (3) Конец изменения.

Comment: @VladD, каюсь, был неправ )

Comment: Вы, видно, плохо понимаете что делает алгоритм Дейкстры: он находит минимальное расстояние между точками, но при этом он не гарантирует, что будут посещены все точки. Я бы даже сказал, что этот алгоритм гарантирует, что для большинства точек построенный путь не будет проходить по всем точкам. Т.е. от того, что вы найдете расстояние между точками, вы ничего не получите, т.к. эта информация вам в итоге будет не нужна: решение задачи коммивояжера может проходить по таким точкам, что расстояние между исходной и текущей будет далеко не минимальным

Comment: К тому же: если решать эту задачу алгоритмом Дейкстры, то решение простое: от исходной точки до исходной точки расстояние равно нулю. Можно к существующим решениям приплюсовать Дейкстру (хотя бы в виде: при помощи этого алгоритма найдем кратчайшие расстояния до соседних точек), но профита от этого никакого не будет

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Думаю, никак.

Из трёх требований к применимости алгоритма дейкстры нарушаются 2. Ненулевой кратчайший путь из вершины в неё же и то, что любой фрагмент кратчайшего пути сам является кратчайшим путём между соответствующими вершинами.

Возможно, можно как-то применить флойда - там более лояльные требования. Но под применить я имею в виду применить в качестве эвристики. Точное решение задачи коммивояжёра требует полного перебора.